# Оптимизация запроса к двум таблицам (Галерея с текстовым описанием)

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток. 
У меня есть такой вопрос. 
Мне нужно оптимизировать запрос с выборкой значений по лимиту.

или подсказка как спроектировать БАЗУ. Для того что бы было можно было записать текст для события и фотографии к событию.

Это нужно для вставки всех картиок по определенному evrnt_id И разделение 
вывода на страници.

**Входные данные.**

---

```
CREATE TABLE `SRC`(
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ,
`event_id` int(10) NOT NULL ,
`src` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL ,
`alternate` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES TEXTS(id)
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;



CREATE TABLE `TEXTS`(
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ,
`big_text` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
`small_text` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL ,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

---

К этим таблицам запрос такого рода.

```
SELECT t.id,s.src,s.alternate,t.small_text,t.datetime FROM TEXTS as t
INNER JOIN SRC s ON s.event_id=t.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM TEXTS ORDER BY id LIMIT 3 OFFSET 14) t2
ON t.id=t2.id;
```

---

EXPLAIN этого запроса
[image: Запрос номер 1]

---

Вот запрос номер 2

```
SELECT t.id,s.src,s.alternate,t.small_text,t.datetime FROM TEXTS as t
INNER JOIN SRC s ON s.event_id=t.id WHERE event_id=3;
```

вот его EPLAIN

[image: запрос номер 2]

Вот собственно сам вопрос как добиться того что бы небыло прочитанно 17 строк и выведено все что нужно, а выводилось конкретно от 14 id таблици TEXTS.
В общем ускорить запрос, но что бы было разделение по 3 event_id.

Возможно тут дело в организации стуктуры базы нужен совет. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что будет если в первом запросе подзапрос получающий 3 id вынести в `where t.id IN(select id ... limit 3)` потому как теоретически ему должно быть достаточно пересчитать записи только по индексу, не пытаясь получать их целиком в остальной части запроса. И боюсь единственный путь к нормальной скорости выборки при больших значениях OFFSET это обеспечить безразрывность id или скорее создать отдельное поле с сплошной нумерацией. Или хотя бы кеш, вида: выбрали 3 записи, запомнили последний id, в следующий раз берем начиная с этого id+1. Но все эти решения довольно тяжелы и дороги в обслуживании

Comment: Я уже релизовал и как 3 таблици одна связывает две доругие с данными, но мне нужно увидеть как это делают на проектах. А именно как устроенна база и как устроенна запрос к ней. По логике вещей нужно сначала ограничиться лимитом потом присоединять данные но так же вроде бы нельзя

Comment: вообще ваш первый запрос так и должен сделать, сначала отработать лимит, потом к нему подклеивать все остальное. почему он у вас и данные берет по 17 строкам, а не берет 17 строк только в подзапросе сказать сложно. Мое первое предложение по вынесению подзапроса в IN направлено как раз на то, что бы оптимизатор все таки догадался брать только 3 строки

Comment: С другой стороны, если там записей 17, а не тысячи, то можно так и оставить. 95% всех проектов используют именно такую пагинацию. Если же вас все таки offset достаточно большие и текущее быстродействие не устраивает, то я перечислил в первом комменте подходы, которые можно было бы использовать. По каждому из них можно написать статьи страниц по 10, как именно это реализовывать. И дальше все зависит уже от того как часто у вас происходят изменения в texts, характера этих изменений и как часто должны проходить выборки и с какими offset

Comment: И да, по логике вещей нареканий к структуре БД нет. не понимаю какие 3 таблицы тут можно было бы использовать. Дополнительные таблицы могут использоваться только для перенумерации или хранения кеша. Хотя кеш я бы хранил не в MySQL, а в чем то более приспособленном вроде memcached