# PHP Обработка многомерного массива $POST

Tags: php

Есть форма отправки с массивом:

```
<form action="script.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="number[one]" value="111">
<input type="text" name="number[two]" value="222">
<input type="text" name="number[three]" value="333">
<button type="submit">GO</button>
</form>
```

В `script.php` ошибка:

```
if($_POST['number']) {
 $result = $_POST['number'][one],$_POST['number'][three];
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы в $result записалось '111,333'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените эту строку:

```
$result = $_POST['number']['one'] , $_POST['number']['three'];
```

На вот эту:

```
$result = $_POST['number']['one'] . $_POST['number']['three'];
```

Или на эту:

```
$result = $_POST['number']['one'] .','. $_POST['number']['three'];
```

У вас там банальная опечатка.

Comment: К вашему ответу аналогичный комментарий, что и к первому.

Comment: @Visman мой ответ был адресован не вам, но тем не менее, благодарю за внимание. Что касается вашего замечания - тут можно ещё много чего найти "не правильного" _(ключи массива не в кавычках, нет фильтра, и т.п.)_ , однако в вопросе из ПП речь шла не об этом: `Как сделать, чтобы в $result записалось '111,333'?`

Answer (score 2):

как то так

```
if(!empty($_POST['number'])) {
$result = $_POST['number']['one'].','.$_POST['number']['three'];
echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Нельзя доверять данным со стороны http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab76c46af4bd926a7a2298f37f6e83e94bba0673

Comment: @Visman а можешь вот тут подсказать ?? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758364/263547

Comment: @dpi - !empty проверит массив $_POST['number'] и увидит в нём элементы one=null, two=null и three=null, т.е. массив будет не пустой, проверка нарушается. Проверяйте !empty($_POST['number']['one'])

Comment: @KirillKorushkin а можешь мне подмочь вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/758364/263547